# Vertical-align in main css

Tags: css, wordpress, vertical-alignment

I have a wordpress site.

I have tried to add a table to my post.

Here is table code:

```
<table border="1">
    <tr>
        <td rowspan=3>
            area on the left
        </td>
        <td>
            Area on the right-1
        </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>
            Area on the right-2
        </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>
            Area on the right-3
        </td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

After adding the table i see that main css contains a `vertical-align:baseline` for `table`, `tbody`, `caption`, `tr`, `td`,`th`. Because of that area on the right 1 is starting just on the right bottom corner of the area left.

When I remove the `vertical-align` from main css it effects all the site

How I can fix this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the solution like this

```
<table border="1" style="vertical-align:top;">
<tr>
    <td rowspan=3 style="vertical-align:top;">
        area on the left
    </td>
    <td style="vertical-align:top;">
        Area on the right-1
    </td>
</tr>
<tr>
    <td>
        Area on the right-2
    </td>
</tr>
<tr>
    <td>
        Area on the right-3
    </td>
</tr>
```

Answer (score 1):

You can override the property with `vertical-align:top`. Write like this:

```
table{
 vertical-align:top;
}
```